# How can I restructure object to Array of objects to a specific format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have this Object which I want to restructure as shown in the desired output below. The `IngriId` in desired output is just `Date.now()` I am struggling to rearrange this it seems impossible to me .Can this be done in javascript because I am very new to it and I am finding it hard to implement?

Input:

```
const Shopping = {
    "meatsOutput": [
      {
        "val": "Chicken breast"
      }
    ],
    "spicesOutput": [
      {
        "amount": "½ tsp",
        "val": "paprika"
      }
    ],
    "dairyOutput": [
      {
        "amount": "1/2 Cup",
        "val": "yogurt"
      },
      {
        "amount": "1/2 teaspoon",
        "val": "heavy cream"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Desired Output:

```
const ShoppingList = [
      {
          "data": [{
              "value": "Chicken breast",
              "ingrId": "202237423fm16787",
          }],
          "name": "meatsOutput",
      },
      {
          "data": [{
              "amount": "½ tsp",
              "value": "paprika",
              "ingrId": "20223742381r787",
          }],
          "name": "spicesOutput",
      },
      {
          "data": [{
              "amount": "1/2 Cup",
              "value": "yogurt",
              "ingrId": "202237423816787",
          }, ],
          "name": "dairyOutput",
      }
  ]
```

Comment: "_Can this be done in javascript_" - yes.

Comment: where does `ingrId` come from?

Comment: @TKoL - as stated by OP - just `Date.now()`

Comment: What's the output case for `dairyOutput` when there are two ingredients?

Comment: @LeGEC, don't remind me. My flight to Göteborg got canceled.

Comment: @AdamAzad it will add another object to the `data` Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.entries`, you can generate the `[key, value]` pair array, and then, using `Array.prototype.map`, you can change that array to the result you want.

```js
const input = {
  "meatsOutput": [{
    "val": "Chicken breast"
  }],
  "spicesOutput": [{
    "amount": "½ tsp",
    "val": "paprika"
  }],
  "dairyOutput": [{
      "amount": "1/2 Cup",
      "val": "yogurt"
    },
    {
      "amount": "1/2 teaspoon",
      "val": "heavy cream"
    }
  ]
};

const result = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => ({
  name: key,
  data: value.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    ingrId: Date.now()
  }))
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for this Answer!!!! . How would I manipulate this if the input was wrapped in an array?

Comment: If `input` is array, you can make like this. `const result = input.map((item) => Object.entries(item)...same...);`